# Windows 10 cannot see all partitions on external hard drive partitioned in Mac OS's diskutil

Tags: partitioning, disk-utility, disk-management

Short Story: I partitioned an external hard drive in Disk Utility, and now Windows 10 can only see the first 2 partitions.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Long Story: I have an early 2014 11" Macbook Air running MacOS 10.12.1 Sierra with a bootcamp partition running Windows 10 Anniversary Edition.
I partitioned my 2TB hard drive to have several partitions a while ago, and Windows 10 recognized them fine (except for the Mac OS Extended Journaled, Encrypted Partition which it did not see). I repartitioned it to have 12 yesterday, and now Windows only recognizes the first 2 partitions. I did not update either OS between the two times I partitioned, though.
Here is what I see after typing in `diskutil list` in Terminal:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Spencers_HD             240.2 GB   disk2s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data INFO                    31.9 GB    disk2s3
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage Time_Machin             255.9 GB   disk2s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s14
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data Scratch_L_W             127.9 GB   disk2s5
   7:       Microsoft Basic Data Scratch_S_W             32.0 GB    disk2s6
   8:                  Apple_HFS Scratch_L_M             127.8 GB   disk2s7
   9:                  Apple_HFS Scratch_S_M             31.9 GB    disk2s8
  10:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows_HD              511.5 GB   disk2s9
  11:          Apple_CoreStorage Ice_HD                  512.2 GB   disk2s10
  12:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s11
  13:       Microsoft Basic Data Linux                   127.6 GB   disk2s12

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Ice_HD                 +511.8 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s10
                                 B25FDB00-C746-436B-BEE4-7563F4281362
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk4 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Time_Machin            +255.5 GB   disk4
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s4
                                 D9A55D8A-F71E-4314-AD10-F5C3BF149196
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

And here's the output I get from diskpart's `list disk`, `list partition`, and `list volume` commands in Command Prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.14393.0

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: SPENCERS_LAPTOP

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          233 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online         1863 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            200 MB    512 B
  Partition 2    Primary            223 GB   200 MB
  Partition 3    Primary             29 GB   224 GB
  Partition 4    Primary            238 GB   253 GB

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   Windows_10   NTFS   Partition     70 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         EFI          FAT32  Partition    200 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     S   Spencers_HD  exFAT  Partition    223 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     D   INFO         FAT32  Partition     29 GB  Healthy

DISKPART>
```

Before I repartitioned it, the partition "Spencers_HD" took the space up until Windows_HD. (So Windows_HD, Ice_HD, and Linux have not been changed.) The partitions labeled "Ice_HD" and "Time_Machin" are encrypted if that matters.
Here are screenshots to Mac OS's Disk Utility app and Windows 10's DiskManagment program, if they help.
[Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi5h6.png)
[DiskManagement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ5Il.png) (scrolling down on this screen did not show anything)

Answer (score 0):

Disk0 is [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) but disk1 is
[MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record).
MBR can only handle disks up to 2 TB and up to 4 primary partitions.

To break the limit of 4 partitions, you will need to convert disk1 to GPT.
See the article
[How to Convert a MBR Disk to a GPT Disk](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26193-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-disk.html).

On an external USB disk, Windows can only see the first partition,
so I don't understand your saying that it can see two of them,
unless you have converted the external disk to internal.
But then I can see that diskpart lists 4 partitions, so I'm still confused.